# Paasing authentication header to javax.websocket ClientEndpoint

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to connect to websocket server endpoint using below code but I am not able to resolve `container.connectToServer(this, cec, uri);` this. This method is not able to take my class as Endpoint class. It's a spring boot project. If I don't pass config then it accepts but then it fails to connect to server and return 401. I have tried many online links but failed to resolve this issue. Need help in how to fix it.

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class TestClassEndpoint {
  private Session userSession = null;

  public TestClassEndpoint(URI uri) {
    try {
      WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
      ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder
          .create().configurator(new ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator() {
            public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
              System.out.println("Setting user cookie in beforeRequest ...");
              headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic base64encodedString"));
            }
          }).build();
      container.connectToServer(this, cec, uri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    this.userSession = session;
    System.out.println("New connection established");
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    this.userSession = null;
    System.out.println("connection closed");
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
  }

  private void sendMessage(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(buffer);
  }

}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TwilioPocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("server_url").build().toUri();
        new TestClassEndpoint(uri);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "annotation" style of WebSocket coding, as you are here, you have to pass the configurator class as an optional element of the annotation, rather than as a parameter to the *connectToServer* method. You were trying to use a mix of the "annotation" and "interface" style of API. So:

```
@ClientEndpoint(configurator=MyConfigurator.class)
```

and then define your configurator class like you have done, overriding the *beforeRequest* method:

```
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator;

public class MyConfigurator extends Configurator {

   public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
       System.out.println("Setting user cookie in beforeRequest ...");
       headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic base64encodedString"));
   }

}
```